# Manage Swapping between two cells rather than changing the NSIndexpath of other UITableViewcells

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview

I know it's the default property of rearrangement of tableviewcells when UITableView is in editing mode & user just reorder the Rows which is handled by UITableViewController.

As per Apple Doc : [Reordering of Rows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)

Now what I want to do is, when I drag the cell over other cells, the backend cells should not get rearranged automatically, just the cell on which I drop the dragged cell should gets rearranged, a kind of **Swapping between two cells**.

For better understanding, please refer the below image. I should be able to **Shift Jones to Room1 & the tableview controller should able to automatically be shifting Smith2 to Room3.**

[image]

*Below are delegates methods which I am using :*

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSString *temp = [roomstoringArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [roomstoringArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

    [roomstoringArray insertObject:temp atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

   // [temp release];

}
```

**Problem is :**

1. How can I stop other cells to get rearranged automatically while I
   am dragging the cells over other.
2. There none of the delegate method which gets called when one used to
   Drag the cell over others, only method called is
   **moveRowAtIndexPath** when one drop the cell on it. So, even can't check for some condition & didn't find any scope of this enhancement
   within existing TableView.

Is there any property with the TableView where I can stop such kind of behavior to perform the swapping between two cells only where rest of rows remain at the same indexPath.Alos, can someone please help me out with some-other way,if any.

Answer (score 0):

For Problem you mention, Please check UITableView Delegates from [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:)

Below methods are helpful to you.

> **targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath** 
>   **canMoveRowAtIndexPath**

For Swap b/w two rows you can get idea by this [**answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748316/how-can-swap-row-at-fromindex-to-toindex-in-uitableview)